# Fabric/Crashlytics won't install appon iPhone 5/c saying armv7s build is needed, however that is set in the architectures

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I'm trying to distribute an app via Fabric/Crashlytics/Beta.

It won't install on a 5 or 5c with the message saying that a build supporting device architecture armv7s is needed.

I have two questions:

Firstly armv7s has been added to the architectures section for the app, and to a framework it uses. Xcode has been cleaned, the derived data folder has been deleted, Xcode has been closed/relaunched, all the usual tricks to get round Xcode foibles. Then after building the archive and uploaded to Fabric, there is still this message. Why?

[image]

Secondly. If armv7s architecture is needed to run on 5 and 5c, then why does this problem only manifest when installing via Fabric? - if the app is loaded onto these devices via XCode there are no problems.

Answer (score 2):

By default XCode sets **Build Valid Architectures Only** to true for debug builds - the consequence of this is if you have an iPhone plugged into your Mac when you are creating the archive and its a development distribution then it will only build the architecture for whatever device happens to be connected at that time and not for all specified architectures.